# How to randomly place symbols in a grid? - Python 3.4.3

Tags: python

Lets say I have a 7x7 grid:

```
. . . . . . .
. . . . . . .
. . . . . . .
. . . . . . .
. . . . . . .
. . . . . . .
. . . . . . .
```

How would I randomly place 0 in rows/col of 3 anywhere in the grid?

```
. . . . . . .
. . . . . . .
. . 0 0 0 . .
. . . . . . .
. . . . . 0 .
. . . . . 0 .
. . . . . 0 .
```

Comment: how many blocks do you need? can they overlap?

Comment: Can you please show any of the code you've written so far?

Answer (score 0):

You randomize the orientation... Horizontal or vertical. 
Then you randomize two numbers for the position of the "000", but do it depending on the orientation. One number is in range(0, 7) and the other is in range(0, 7-3). The "-3" part is so that it doesn't get placed outside the board.

Here's some python code...

```
from random import randint

def place_randomly(grid):
    orientation = ['h', 'v'][randint(0, 1)] #randomly choose orientation

    if orientation == 'h':
        x = randint(0, 4)
        y = randint(0, 6)
        grid[y][x] = grid[y][x+1] = grid[y][x+2] = '0'
    elif orientation == 'v':
        x = randint(0, 6)
        y = randint(0, 4)
        grid[y][x] = grid[y+1][x] = grid[y+2][x] = '0'
    print "XY:", x, y

def print_grid(grid):
    for i in grid:
        for j in i:
            print j,
        print ""

for i in range(10): # try it out 10 times
    grid = [['.' for x in range(7)] for x in range(7)]
    place_randomly(grid)
    print_grid(grid)
    print ""
```